# do-release upgrade fails with KeyError: "The cache has no package named 'ubuntu-minimal'"

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to upgrade ubuntu server from 16.04 to 18.04 using `do-release-upgrade` but it errors out right at the start with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-074vyz42/bionic", line 8, in 
<module> 
sys.exit(main()) 

File 
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-074vyz42/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", 
line 238, in main 
if app.run(): 

File 
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-074vyz42/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", 
line 2053, in run 
return self.fullUpgrade() 

File 
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-074vyz42/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", 
line 1936, in fullUpgrade 
if not self.cache.anyVersionDownloadable(self.cache[pkg]): 

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 233, in 
__getitem__ 
raise KeyError('The cache has no package named %r' % key) 

KeyError: "The cache has no package named 'ubuntu-minimal'"
```

It looks like this bug, but the bug report is from a few months ago and hasn't had any attention. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1795207

ubuntu-minimal is neither unstalled nor available:

```
root@tooticky:~# apt install ubuntu-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-minimal
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue. My solution was to clear all cached packages before trying to update again. `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` followed by `sudo apt-get update` worked for me. After the update you can check the version of Ubuntu with `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: After doing the `sudo rm ...`, I had to wait about 5 mins until the OS detected the cache as cleared. If I wanted to continue immediately, I got: "Checking for a new Ubuntu release Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading." for `sudo do-release-upgrade`. // Additionally, and this was even more painful, the "archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu.list.distUpgrade" file still referred to focal. I just commented out this line and continued with jammy in the "archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu.list" file for the best experience.